# Limit with integral functions: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\int_x^{x+1}f(t)dt-\int_0^{1}f(t)dt}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be continous in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)+1=f(1)$
Compute the limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\dfrac{\int_x^{x+1}f(t)dt-\int_0^{1}f(t)dt}{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\dfrac{F(x+1)-F(x)-F(1)+F(0)}{x}}$$

**WRONG attempt:**

I used L'Hopital: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}{F(x+1)-F(x)-F(1)+F(0)}$

By hypothesis $f(0)+1=f(1)$ so I integrated both sides: $F(1)-F(0)=x+c$

So: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}{F(x+1)-F(x)-x+c}$

Then it should be $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}x-x+c_1$ which equals to $c_1$. Am I  right?

**EDIT (Final attempt)**

I made a mistake with L'Hopital (I integrated instead of differentiating)

So (using L'Hopital)

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{1}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x+1)-f(x)=1$$

Comment: Did you miss out the divided by $x$?

Comment: If you integrate $f(0)+1=f(1)$ on both sides, it should be $xf(0)+x=f(1)x+c$ since both sides are constants...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you recall the definition of a derivative is $f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ This limit can be seen as the derivative $h(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ at $x=0$. By the second fundamental theorem of calculus $h'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, at $x=0$ we get $f(1)-f(0)$

Answer (score 2):

Let,   $$ \phi(x) = F(x+1)-F(x)  = \int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt $$ with 
$$ F(x) =\int_0^x f(t) dt$$
hence $\phi'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$

Then the answer is 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\dfrac{\int_x^{x+1}f(t)dt-\int_0^{1}f(t)dt}{x}}=  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x) -\phi(0)}{x} =\color{red}{\phi'(0)=  f(1)-f(0) = 1.}$$

Comment: Where did I do wrong in the new attempt?

Comment: The following statement is not correct at all $f(1) -f(0)  = 1\implies F(1)-F(0) = x +c$ if you integrate both sides you should got $xf(1) -xf(0)  = x$ instead. But rather $F(1)-F(0)=\int_0^1 f(t)dt $

Comment: I finally got it right, I hope

Answer (score 0):

Hint the form is $\frac {0}{0} $ so we can use L hospital rule  combined with Newton leibnitz theorem  . So we have $L=lim x\to 0
(f(x+1)-f (x))=f (1)-f (0)=1$